# autocomplete combobox for vb.net word by word or with delimiters

Tags: vb.net, autocomplete

I am trying to add word by word (and/or with delimiter support) autocomplete functionality to a combobox (or textbox) in a vb.net application. This is the desired behavior, stripped down to one delimiter for this question:

When the user types 'invoke XX ' in the box, a list of suggested words should pop up. The user should still be able to type through, continually filtering those words, until he/she selects one. For example:

> 'invoke 121 ' *(should prompt a list of words such as Display, DVD, CD, still with typethrough)*

I can handle much of the actual logic, but I'm pretty new to vb.net, and I'm unsure of the best way to trigger an autocomplete popup on a space (or period), word by word. (Regular combobox autocomplete doesn't support word by word.) This post looks helpful but I don't know how to convert the accepted answer's developer-express tools into regular .net components: [autocomplete text box for .net with support for delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560655/autocomplete-text-box-for-net-with-support-for-delimiter). Ideally it'd work a lot like intellisense.

Here is my attempt so far (just a form with a textbox), stripped down. I need help figuring out how to allow typing to filter through the contextmenustrip. I also wonder if I'd be better off with something other than a contextmenustrip. Thanks

```
   Public Class Form1

        Private WithEvents firstContextMenu As ContextMenuStrip

        ' Populate items for the contextmenustrip
        Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            firstContextMenu = New ContextMenuStrip()
            firstContextMenu.Items.Add("Display")
            firstContextMenu.Items.Add("DVD")
            firstContextMenu.Items.Add("CD")
        End Sub

        ' Bring up the contextmenustrip if typing a space, if after 'invoke XX '
        Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
            If e.KeyChar = " " And TextBox1.Text.StartsWith("invoke ", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) And TextBox1.Text.Split().Length = 2 Then
                TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + " "     ' Add a space
                TextBox1.Select(TextBox1.Text.Length, 0)    ' To put the cursor at the end of the textbox
                Dim point As New System.Drawing.Point(TextBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(DirectCast(sender, TextBox).SelectionStart - 1).X, TextBox1.Height - 5)
                firstContextMenu.Show(TextBox1, point, ToolStripDropDownDirection.BelowRight)
            End If
        End Sub

        ' Adds the clicked item to the textbox
        Private Sub firstContextMenu_ItemClicked1(sender As Object, e As ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs) Handles firstContextMenu.ItemClicked
            TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text + e.ClickedItem.ToString()
            TextBox1.Select(TextBox1.Text.Length, 0)
        End Sub

        ' Moves cursor to end of textbox if you 'escape' out of the contextmenustrip
        Private Sub firstContextMenu_Closed(sender As Object, e As ToolStripDropDownClosedEventArgs) Handles firstContextMenu.Closed
            TextBox1.Select(TextBox1.Text.Length, 0)
        End Sub

    End Class
```

Comment: Have you seen the 'AutoComplete' property?

Comment: @CodingSource I'ved tried it. It autocompletes the contents of the entire box at once (like a Google search box does), with no flexibility to autocomplete word by word, for instance.